# This simple code should work but I am getting warning

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int *i = new int;
*i = 0;
int &j = *i;
j++;

//cout << *i << endl;
```

I have a code like that, and I know this syntax is true but it gives warning in Visual Studio Code like this:

```
quiz2_q8.cpp:5:4: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token
 *i = 0;
    ^
quiz2_q8.cpp:7:1: error: 'j' does not name a type
 j++;
```

Am I missing a library to include? I thought iostream is enough for this quiz code.

Comment: Yeah, I am such an idiot; it was a quiz question and I thought the problem was in syntax. I noticed later that there is not main function. Sorry for time wasting. Sorry for late update; I forgot that I asked this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have arbitrary statements in the global namespace. You need to put it into a function, e.g. like this:

```
int main() {
  int *i = new int;
  *i = 0;
  int &j = *i;
  j++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most programs have a starting point, which is the main method/function/procedure whatever you want to call it. Each function has a scope given by **{ // fun scope  }**. A good tutorial series on C++ might come to your aid, or perhaps a book. With that said here's a template for such a program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   
    
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Statements for being executed must be inside functions.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) { // add this

    int *i = new int;
    *i = 0;
    int &j = *i;
    j++;

    //cout << *i << endl;

} // add this
```